# Which data structure and algorithm I should look into to be able to implement a compilation of data from different sources with precedence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The requirements of my problem is:

- Standardize the data from different sources by creating a standard shape of the object. Because these different sources may have different object shapes, some fields might have data and some might not.
- The data will be compiled based on priority. Meaning whichever of these data sources that has highest priority will be the source of the values to hydrate the final object.
- Priority can be configured for the whole object or at the field level. Meaning, the configured priority at the field level can override the whole objects priority of the data source.
- If a field is null, it will look on the next data source based on its priority.

Pseudo Code

```
Whole object priority is the default.
interface SampleStandardData {
   field1 <-- priority here should override the whole object's priority
   field2
   field3 <-- can be a nested object
}

/**
*  different data sources that conforms to the standard
*  shape. If fields are missing from the sources then
*  the field will be null.
*/ 
const dataSources: Array<SampleStandardData> = [
  DataSourceOne,
  DataSourceTwo,
]

/**
* Conclude which data made it to the final object 
* that each could come from different sources
*/
const finalObject: SampleStandardData = compile(
  dataSources,   // Expecting to accept multiple data sources
  priorityConfig, // Configure priority one way or another
)
```

I am new to DS and Algo. I am currently going to implement a poor man's version of it with what I currently know (I might just use arrays and iterate and add logic). I'll update it here once I think I have a good progress. I am just hoping that someone could point me into the right direction (hoping I could jump directly instead of studying all and learn if there is something I can use) to know which existing solutions I could look into and study.

Comment: If data source with highest priority miss a field, but that field is present in another data source, should the field be hydrated ?

Comment: Are the object flat, or could there be field that are object themselves ? Could these objects implement a different "SampleStandardData" interface ?

Comment: @AloisChristen If the field is missing then it will look for the next data source in the priority list. If still nothing then it will just be null.

Comment: @AloisChristen It can be a nested object.

Comment: Quick though : make an interface with each field being an ordered set of sources. This will be the priority of the source for that field. You can complete these priority sets with the priorityConfig when you construct the object. An interresting question now is how you fetch data from the sources : if the loading is time consuming, you may want to load the full objects from each source. But if the object have many fields, you may want to only load not-currently-present fields.

Comment: @AloisChristen at the moment, we load everything first then do the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is, I created a typescript utility type that accepts the data source shape/type and replaces the field properties with a number that represents the priority.

```
type Data {
  fieldOne: string
}

type Priority = number
 
const configuration: ConvertToPriorityConfig<Data> = {
    fieldOne: 100 // <-- fieldOne is now type Priority
}
```

This utility type is also recursive for nested objects

The merger now accepts an array of data sources that are paired with its own configuration.